# How do you adjust the transparency/opacity of active and non-active sections in the beamer footer?

Tags: beamer, pdftex, header-footer, boxes

I'm using pdflatex, beamer class, boxes theme.

I have a footline with the sections of my document listed there. It slightly grays out the non-active section titles in the footer, but not enough.

How do I alter the transparency of non-active section headings in the footer?

```
\setbeamertemplate{footline} {
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \pgfsetfillopacity{95}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=1.0\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}%
    \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{.8\paperwidth}{}{}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the level of dimming via the `section in head/foot shaded` template. Adjust the value `[10]` to your liking.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{footline} {
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
%  \pgfsetfillopacity{95}
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=1.0\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{section in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}%
    \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{.8\paperwidth}{}{}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  }
}

\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot shaded}[default][10]

\begin{document}
    
\section{test}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\section{test}
\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]